# how to fit lines to edges and find the center point (opencv)

Tags: opencv, line, adaptive-threshold

I have an image to which I apply a bilateral filter, followed by adaptive thresholding to get the image below.

original image (this is a screenshot off the depth image of the object) [image]

thresholded image[image]

I would like to fit lines to the vertical parts/lines and find the center poiint, output like image below:

[image]

I cant seem to understand the output of the [cv2.adaptiveThreshold()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga72b913f352e4a1b1b397736707afcde3). How are the purple pixels (i.e my edges) represented? and how can a line be fitted? MWE:

```html
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("depth_frame0009.jpg")
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

bilateral_filter = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray_image, 15, 50, 50)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(bilateral_filter)
plt.title("bilateral filter")
#plt.imsave("2dimage_gaussianFilter.png",blurred)
plt.imsave("depthmap_image_bilateralFilter.png",bilateral_filter)


th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(bilateral_filter,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(th3)
```

========

edit:

Canny edges [image]
contours [image]

Answer (score 0):

They are represented as an image, a matrix of uint8.

The reason it is purple and yellow is because matplotlib is applying a colormap to it.

I generally prefer to use some specific parameters when plotting image processing output images, eg

```
plt.imshow(th3, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
```

If you are specifically interested in finding and fitting lines you may want to use a different representation, such as [Hough lines](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html).  Once you have the lines in the image you can take the best fit lines and find your center point between them.

Comment: it looks white and black now (instead of purple and yellow). Applying hough lines to the output of the adaptiveThreshold doesnt work, just 1 diagonal line going through the entire image. Trying hough lines on the output of cv2.Canny() can detect only the horizontal line

Comment: I would do Hough lines on the original image.

Comment: I dont think that would work. In the documentation of [houghlines()](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html) they do it after getting the Canny edges. I tired on the original, gray image, adaptiveThreshold, but in all cases houglines() doesnt work. Only w
hen i use the canny edges as input, it detects the horizontal line only:
![hough_lines_image](https://imgur.com/3HmIDTB).

Comment: Sharing the original image would be more helpful to finding a solution that works.